# Appcelerator Titanium updateRow is working strange

Tags: android, titanium

I used updateRow for updating row! after updating instead of this row display empty row ( displaying only hasChild but without any word )

```
if(CustomData[6].name == 'Starts'){

var time = p.value;
var test = new Object();
test = {name:&quot;Starts&quot;, status:time, hasChild:true};
TheTable.updateRow(e.index, test);

}
```

Comment: Which version of your titanium SDK?